# Facebook Connector Error

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, winforms, oauth-2.0

I need to create Facebook connector like as ODBC Facebook connector in desktop application.

It has many parameters like **`Driver, Callback URL, OAuth Client Id, OAuth Client Secret,_persist_oauthexpiresin,_persist_oauthaccesstoken,_persist_token_timestamp`**.

I had **`DRIVER, Callback URL,OAuth Client Id,OAuth Client Secret`** parameters, but I don’t have others like **`_persist_oauthexpiresin,_persist_oauthaccesstoken,_persist_token_timestamp`**.its creating automatically, without these parameters I am not able to connect my Facebook connector.

Please tell anyone how to create these parameter values or simply tell any other way to connect my Facebook connector without these parameters.

[image: Without these parameters I getting following error]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using following connection string to connect facebook.

```
DRIVER={CData ODBC Driver for Facebook};Other='InitiateOAuth=GETANDREFRESH;CheckPromptMode=false;OAuth SettingsLocation=C:\Users\Test\New Text Document.txt';
```

Here `'OAuth SettingsLocation'` is a text file that contain access token of our facebook account.

I hope It's useful.It's work for me.